# how to show an marshmallow sheme in drf-aysg swagger web UI as example of request_body

Tags: django-rest-framework, marshmallow, drf-yasg

The project I'm working on:

1) works with more than 20 external data sources and there will only be more of them (rest api, xmlrpc, boto and boto3, xml, etc.) In the main use **marshmallow** schemes

2) more than 100 API methods are planned (using **django-rest-marshmallow**)

3) The entire API description is maintained through the library **drf-aysg** using **openapi.Schema**

I want to make all serialization/deserialization operations in the project the same. For this purpose I want to use the **marshmallow** library

openapi Schema discribes input API data

```py
PackageCreateDomainSchema = openapi.Schema(
    title="Mass Domain Creation",
    type=openapi.TYPE_OBJECT,
    required=["domains"],
    properties={
        'domains': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_ARRAY, items=openapi.Items(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING)),
    },
)
```

API description decorator

```py
@swagger_auto_schema(
    request_body=PackageCreateDomainSchema,
    operation_summary="Package Domain adding",
    tags= ['Tag1', "Tag2"],
    responses= {
         201: openapi.Response('Domain added', CreateDomainSchema , examples=[{"created": 5, "exists": ['example.com'] }])
    }
)
```

I want use this code instead first block

```py
from rest_marshmallow import Schema, fields

class PackageCreateDomainSchema(Schema):
    domains = fields.List(fields.String(), required=True)
```

But Swagger web UI show last class definition only as ***string*** not as ***dict with lists of strings***

How to make the library **drf-yasg** render the **marchmallow** to **complex object** (not as the default value - string)